# get dpkg --get-selections equivalent list from dpkg.status.0

Tags: dpkg

My SSD crashed, and I can't find the output from `dpkg --get-selections` that I created recently. 
However, I could make a copy of the `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0` file from the broken ssd. I feel like all the information, that `dpkg --get-selections` gave me is in there, but in the wron format. And I feel like, there must be a command, that allows to convert it (rather that writing a script myself).
Question: What is that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically from what im thinking is that all applications in `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0` have `install ok installed` line so you will only have to use this command to get same output of `dpkg --get-selections`: `grep "Package" < /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 | awk '{print $2"\t\tinstall"}'`. Check it.

Comment: perfect! I was expecting something that invokes dpkg, but this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you check where `dpkg --get-selections` is getting it's raw data from. If you suspect it's getting the data from /var, then you can further narrow down the results with a grep. Like this:

```
strace dpkg --get-selections 2>&1 | grep /var
```

That will produce the following result:

```
open("/var/lib/dpkg/updates/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/var/lib/dpkg/available", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/var/lib/dpkg/triggers//File", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

Then, if you wonder where that `dpkg` backup file came from, you can search your cron files for mentions of `dpkg`:

```
 grep -R dpkg /etc/cron*
```

From that, you could figure out that `/var/backup/dpkg.status.0` was first backed up and then rotated, based on `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Putting the above together, you get `dpkg --get-selections` to produce the report you want, by temporarily restoring your "dpkg status" file back to `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and then running `dpkg --get-selections`. It will now reference your backup data.